# Two similar loops - One works perfectly, the other doesn't

Tags: c

The following function is part of my program. The purpose of this function is to scan through a large text file and count the number of occurences (`NameAppearences`) of the names read from another file. The names read from the second file are stored in an array declared globally as `char **Names`. The following version of the function works as expected when it counts the number of occurences of `Names[0]`:

```
void SearchForNames()
{
    char LineOfText[85];
    char *TempName;
    char word[15];

    while(fgets(LineOfText, sizeof(LineOfText), fpn))
    {

        strncpy(word, Names[0], strlen(Names[0]) - 1);
        TempName = strstr(LineOfText, word);
        if(TempName != NULL)
        {
            NameAppearances++;
        }

    }
    printf("%d", NameAppearances);
}
```

However, if I alter this `while` loop to include a nested `for` loop in order to count the number of occurences of all of the names (`Names[0]` to `Names[NumOfNames]`, it prints a value of 0 for `NameAppearances`:

```
while(fgets(LineOfText, sizeof(LineOfText), fpn))
{
    for(x=0; x<NumOfNames; x++)
    {
        strncpy(word, Names[x], strlen(Names[x]) - 1);
        TempName = strstr(LineOfText, word);
        if(TempName != NULL)
        {
            NameAppearances++;
        }
    }
}
printf("%d", NameAppearances);
```

I do not understand why this slight change in the loop causes it to work incorrectly.

Comment: What is `NumOfNames` its not 0?

Comment: Another function in the program counts the number of names in the file containing the names and stores this number in `NumOfNames`. I have ran the program with two different files of names, one in which `NumOfNames = 20` and the other in which `NumOfNames = 64`. Both returned 0 as the value for `NameAppearances`.

Comment: Why not just `TempName = strstr(LineOfText, Names[0]);`? This also gets rid of the issue with `strncpy()` that you have (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4768271/439599) ).

Comment: I tired using `strstr` but I was having terrible issues with the program. For some strange reason (I think it has to do with the way the two files are formatted with newlines, null terminators etc.). When the program scanned the text file it only recognised names that were the last word of a line. I eventually eliminated this problem by using strncpy with `n = strlen(Names[0]) - 1`

Answer (score 1):

`strncpy(word, Names[0], strlen(Names[0]) - 1); TempName = strstr(LineOfText, word);` is undefined behavior.

`word` has no null character termination yet is used as string in `strstr()`.

---

[Edit]

The following for string manipulation is bad.  It leaves `word` with a copy of `Names[0]` except for a missing `'\0'`.

```
strncpy(word, Names[0], strlen(Names[0]) - 1);  // bad code
```

Instead to prevent buffer over-run use

```
word[0] = 0;
strncat(word, Names[0], sizeof word - 1);
```

---

[Edit 2]

Based on your other posts, insure your list of names have their `'\n'` removed.

```
    LineOfText[strcspn(LineOfText, "\n")] = 0;
    Names[x] = strdup(LineOfText);
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I now understand why it is UB. I am struggling to understand, though, how I can implement the use of `strcspn` in my function if it just returns the length of the string up to `'\n'` and so returns the same value as `strlen(Names[0]) - 1`

Comment: `strcspn(buffer, "\n")` does _not_ return the same value as `strlen(Names[0]) - 1`.  That only holds true if `buffer` ended with a `"\n"`, which is not always the case.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I'm making progress... But I'm still really struggling creating the loop that scans the entire file and searches for each and all of the names while counting their total appearances. I'm failing to grasp how I can implement your recommendations of using `strncat` etc. 

One of my main problems was having the newline character included after all the names in my array so I'm delighted to have cleared that up now.

Comment: It seems to all be working fine now! The only problem I have to eliminate is if two names appear on the same line, it recognises the first one and then moves on to the next line before reaching the second name

Comment: @KOB, certainly the "two name" problem is separate from this.  Being precise helps.  What is your code's definition of "name"? a group of mixed case A-Z letters? Spaces? What about "Al Smith-Brown" "Pele", "Joan A. Smith", "Pat O'Brian", _Can a last name contain a space?_ [The artist formerly known as Prince](http://www.rollingstone.com/music/lists/the-25-boldest-career-moves-in-rock-history-20110318/prince-changes-his-name-to-an-unpronounceable-symbol-20110323)

Comment: Luckily all the names are single words of just A-Z letters. I have everything sorted out now, thanks for all of your help!